# play scalaJson how to retrieve record when querying for value

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

So I am having a couple problems with Play's scalaJSON. First being that I am somehow not able to make my keys anything other than strings. I have defined a a JSONWrites converter as follows:

```
implicit val musics = new Writes[Question] {
      def writes(question:Question) = Json.obj(
        "questionID" -> question.questionID,
        "questionText" -> question.questionText,
        "responseURI" -> question.responseURI,
        "constraints: min,max,Optional" -> Json.arr(question.minResponse, question.maxResponse, question.optionalQ),
        "responseDataType" -> question.responseDataType
      )
    }
```

my model case class for question:

```
case class Question (questionID:Int,
                      questionText:String,
                      responseURI:String,
                      minResponse:Option[Int],
                      maxResponse:Option[Int],
                      optionalQ:Boolean,
                      responseDataType:String)
```

When desigining my REST API in play, I wanted to access the specific question of this survey app with a url such as `/questionBlock/questionID`

I tried to simply make the question.questionID the parent key and nest the rest of the JSON as the value to this key, but it would not allow me to do this, saying `expected String actual Int`

the actual JSON rendered out looks like this:

```
  [{"questionID":0,"questionText":"What is your favorite musical artist?",
"responseURI":"/notDoneYet","constraints: min,max,Optional":[1,1,false],
"responseDataType":"String"},{"questionID":1,"questionText":"What is your favorite music genre?",
"responseURI":"/notDoneYet","constraints: min,max,Optional":[1,1,false],"responseDataType":"String"}]
```

But using this I cannot seem to figure out how to return the entire field where questionID equals 1 or 2 etc. I have used the 0th, 1st, etc element of the array but that is not the ideal approach for me, since question Ids may not always start at 0 for a particular sequence of questions.

Basically, I want to be able to show an entire record for one question when I provide the value of questionID. In Javascript I would have made the outermost key this questionID value, but I am unable to figure out how to do this using scalaJson. If there is an alternative way to accomplish this, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: can you add, your  class Question, thanks

Comment: i have added my Question case class after editing, thank you

Comment: Your problem is unclear, try to rephrase your last paragraph and provide an example of what you would like to achieve.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your question?

Comment: honestly... this question is not relevant anymore. i dont even understand what my problem was here after re-reading it. i've redesigned my api functionality since this time so i think i've been able to solve it using a different approach altogether